# Changing Content Type Questions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This question has been answered a few times but I can't seem to put the solution together. What I have below is what I'm glued together through various forums. I'm also new to WPF. I'm trying to switch the content of the MainWindow.xaml based some parameters. What I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LogsGriDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ViewModel1}">
        <Label>This is a log</Label>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReportsGridDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ViewModel2}">
        <Label>This is a report</Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />

private ViewModel1 _viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
private ViewModel2 _viewModel2 = new ViewModel2();

private DataTemplate _CurrentPageViewModel;
public DataTemplate CurrentPageViewModel 
{
    get { return _CurrentPageViewModel; }
    set { Set(() => CurrentPageViewModel, ref _CurrentPageViewModel, value); } 
}

public void OnButtonPressMethod(object param)
{
    if (view == 0)
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = _viewModel1;
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = _viewModel1;
    }
}
```

The compiler is complaining about the CurrentPageViewModel = _viewModel1/2 statement saying you cannot set type ViewModel to type DataTemplate which makes sense. What should the CurrentPageViewModel property be? Is there anything else wrong with this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding source should be your view model, not a `DataTemplate`.  The `DataTemplate` with `DataType` definition in XAML will automatically bind content to the data template that matches the type.

So you could create a common interface/base class for view models 1 & 2:

```
public interface IViewModel { }
public class ViewModel1 : IViewModel { }
public class ViewModel2 : IViewModel { }

private IViewModel _viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
private IViewModel _viewModel2 = new ViewModel2();

private IViewModel _CurrentPageViewModel;
public IViewModel CurrentPageViewModel 
{
    get { return _CurrentPageViewModel; }
    set { Set(() => CurrentPageViewModel, ref _CurrentPageViewModel, value); } 
}
```

Comment: I also need clarification on this statement ->DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ViewModel2}" Does this set the data context for that data template to ViewModel2 or do I need to switch the context in the code?

Comment: @KrisW well, it doesn't set the data context as such.  It tells the XAML compiler to bind objects of type ViewModel2 to this data template.  So then when you set your content control to the ViewModel2 instance, the "ReportsGridDataTemplate" will be applied, at it will have the data context of that view model instance.

Comment: As an alternative to using interfaces here, I prefer to use a `BaseViewModel` and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in it so that the other view models don't have to. In this way, my property looks more like this (but they'll both work in the same way): `public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }`. (This was just a comment for the question author)